# Pop up errors using wine (PolerStars and PartyPoker)

Tags: wine

I'm currently using wine 3.04 in Ubuntu 18.04, i have installed PokerStars and partypoker, but both aren't working very well. When a "pop up" from these programs appears wine opens an error message and the pop up window completely crashes, so i cant close it... The message says "the program pwgebrenderer.exe has a found a serious problem and need to be close..." "that might have been caused by a problem in wine....". I want to know how to solve this error and play my games. I'm sorry if i written something imprecise or wrong , I am new here and English is not my native language.

[image: here is an image showing what happens]

Comment: You might want to [install latest devel](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) version of Wine, and then try again. Wine is a project working toward a moving target *(that is, compatibility with Windows versions up to duplicating Windows bugs if there're apps that rely on this)*, and new version being released every two weeks with a lot of improvements. For writing the words the latest devel version is [4.0rc1](https://www.winehq.org/announce/4.0-rc1).

Comment: thanks, i tried that but the following message apearred " Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: " i don't no what to do.

Comment: Did you use `apt-add-repository` with the correct repository, which is mentioned in "Ubuntu versions prior to 18.10" paragraph? That is, the `sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`?